# Updating Constraints programmatically?

Tags: swift, autolayout, constraints

I have a subclass of UIView, I want to manipulate a constraint but it does not work.

When pressing a button exchangesViewActivated changes and the functions get called.

```
var exchangesViewActivated = false {
    didSet {
        if exchangesViewActivated == true {
            setExchangesView()
        } else {
            setUpLayout()
        }
    }
}
```

Die subview and translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints are set.

```
func setUpLayout() {

    bottomContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500).isActive = true


    bottomContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewContrainer.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    bottomContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewContrainer.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    bottomContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: configBar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    bottomContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewContrainer.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

}
```

Now I want to manipulate the constraint by calling this function:

```
 func setExchangesView() {

bottomContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewContrainer.bottomAnchor).isActive = false

        bottomContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500).isActive = false
        bottomContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
```

But this constraint stays activated:

> bottomContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500).isActive

Am I missing something? Is it not enough to set a constraint to false to deactivate it? Do I have to call something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setUpLayout()` is adding new constraints every time you call `setUpLayout()` method. You must save constraint reference and update it next time.

For example.

```
// class variable 
var bottomConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint? = nil

bottomConstraint = bottomContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500)
bottomConstraint.isActive = true
```

And later update constraint

```
bottomConstraint.constant = 100
bottomConstraint.isActive = true
```

Comment: I have one question maybe you know, if I remove a UIView from its supervie, do all its constraints also get removed?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't deactivate old constraints as it deactivates the newly created ones so do

```
var heightCon:NSLayoutConstraint!
var botCon:NSLayoutConstraint!
```

//

```
heightCon = bottomContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500)
heightCon.isActive = true

botCon = bottomContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewContrainer.bottomAnchor)
botCon.isActive = true
```

Then you can easily reference the constraints and deactivates them and add the new constraints